# Changing windows Explorer to show organiSe rather than organiZe in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, i18n

Does anyone know if there is any way to change the **Organize** menu in Windows Explorer on Windows 7 say to **Organise** instead?

Normally the lack of British English internationalisation doesn't bother me (I long ago accepted that Britain and the U.S. are two nations divided by a common language *8'), but for some reason, this one *does* bother me. I guess it's because it is right there in your face, at the top of *every* Widnwos Explorer window.

Comment: No there isn't (unless you patch the appropriate files). I believe Microsoft considers it too expensive to warrant a separate build of Windows where most of the words are the same anyway. Never mind the fact that the "z" spelling used to be the authoritative English way anyway :-). Disclosure: I hate it too, but there are other things more important in my life.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft doesn't have an "en-GB" localization like some other operating systems do. They do appear to have UK-specific marketing and technical support pages and associated departments, but they don't have a Language Pack for British English.

The language strings are stored in a not-very-user-friendly `.mui` file in the language pack. The problem is that `MUI` files are covered under Windows Resource Protection (WRP), which means that whenever the files are altered, Windows will automatically detect this alteration as "corruption" and attempt to restore it to the factory default, or the latest patched version of the file from a Windows Update.

More reading about MUI [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319070(v=vs.85).aspx)

More reading about WRP [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Resource_Protection)

It is technically possible to bypass WRP but that's shooting yourself in the foot if you ask me. It's not worth bypassing a critical self-healing feature of Windows just to make the UI look "right" (to you) ;)